# Strange thing with Google nocaptcha

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I have a strange problem with Google Captcha. I've tried all kinds of php codes from different tutorials, but the result is exactly the same every time...

The problem is this:

- it shows up correctly
- if you check the box, it works correctly
- if you then send the form it works correctly
- but... if you *don't* check the box, the form is still sent!

So, in other words, it's only on the form as a decorative piece. What could be the problem? It's probably something very simple, but I'm totally missing it.

Help or insights are very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

***Addendum***

The following is the code that came with the template I used:

```
    require_once('recaptcha-php-1.11/recaptchalib.php');

if ($use_captcha == 1) {

$resp = null;
$error = null;
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);
$secret = "MY SECRET KEY HERE";
$captcha_error_message = '<div class="pi-alert-danger fade in"><button type="button" class="pi-close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></button><p>Bewijs dat je geen robot bent!</p></div>';

if (isset($_POST["captcha_response"]) && $_POST["captcha_response"] != '') {

    $resp = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["captcha_response"]
    );

    if ($resp && $resp->success != true) {
        echo $captcha_error_message;
        exit();
    }

} else {
    echo $captcha_error_message;
    exit();
}

}
```

Comment: code sample will be helful. did you put any checkbox validation during submit?

Comment: I may be wrong, but the point of CAPTCHA is not to prevent the form to be submitted, but to allow you, when recieving the data on server side, to validate it was submit by a human being.

Comment: for that you have to use ajax to check that checkbox is checked or not

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Comment: @mitkosoft: I don't think so. Do you have an example of a checkbox validation I could try? ( I'm not a experienced coder by far... I've built my website form a template and with a lot of copying and pasting code. I can work things out just by analytical thinking, but I can't really write code.)

Comment: There are lot of JavaScript examples how to validate form elements before submit. Check these one for example:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml , 
http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out!

Comment: Hmm, seems that the validators only work on <input>, but the captcha is a div. Can't get it to work. I've tried some other forms of JavaScript validators, but all with the same result...

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the captcha was solved (at your PHP-Script which do anything with the Form-data)

Like this:

```
function checkCaptcha($recaptchaResponse) {
    $recaptchaPrivateKey = 'Your Private Key';

    if(! $recaptchaResponse)
        return false;

    $recaptchaObj = new ReCaptcha($recaptchaPrivateKey);
    $response = $recaptchaObj->verifyResponse($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $recaptchaResponse);

    if($response != null && $response->success)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

If you don't include a function like this to your form function, your server will say, the form is okay, because it don't know about the captcha.

Note, that you have to include the Google-captcha Libarys-File as well. You can find it here:
https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/1.0.0/php/recaptchalib.php (Worked for NoCaptcha as well)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried out the code you gave, but unfortunately it did not work.